# Aligning inputs in Bootstrap columns in different rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

all.

This is driving me nuts. I have two rows within a Bootstrap container. The first row has a single column of col-8 length that contains a single input (A in screenshot). The second row has two columns with each column having a col-4 length and a single input (B and C in the screenshot). Intuitively, I would think the  first input's right border would align with the second input's right border in the second row (since 8 = 4 + 4). Visually, this isn't the case (please see attached screenshot).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8MkD.png)

I am guessing the inputs in the second row have additional padding that makes their combined width different from the first input. What is the best way to make the first input's right border align with the right border of the second input in the second row? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `margin-right:-30px` to col-8 because yes 4+4=8 but the colums have 15px margins on the left and on the right;

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your grid code, check out this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bootstrap Form Layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
    .row {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check out these pages for better understanding of Bootstrap grid system and form layouts:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php

Answer (score 0):

Try check this

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>A</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>B</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>C</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```